# Accessing img from within img.onload after wrapping and passing loop index

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and i'm lost, anybody?

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var Img = new Image();
    Img.onload = (function(index)
    {
        //correct loop index hurrahh
        console.log(i);

        //now i need 'this' as in the original Img, but when wrapped it becomes window
        console.log(this);

    })(i);
    Img.src = "img.png";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you have to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) ( see bellow snippet )

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var Img = new Image();
  Img.onload = (function(i) {

    return function(index) {
      //correct loop index hurrahh
      console.log(i);

      //now i need 'this' as in the original Img, but when wrapped it becomes window
      console.log(this);

    }
  })(i);
  Img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Img.onload=function(){
 alert(this);
};
```

Your code contains an iife, but the code should return a function but it returns nothing.

```
Img.onload=(function(){})();
//is parsed to
Img.onload=
```

Thats why it doesnt work.Also the iife executes now and not at Img load.
 You need to either return a function, or create it a bit different if you want i:

```
(function(i){
//were now in a closure with bound i
Img.onload=function(){
alert(i);
alert(this);//both work
};
})(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set right context use `bind` function.

```
    (function(index) {
        //correct loop index hurrahh
        console.log(index);

        //now i need 'this' as in the original Img, but when wrapped it becomes window
        console.log(this);

    }.bind(Img))(i);
```

Also seems `console.log(i);` should be `console.log(index);` as your IIFE created closure for `i`.

Comment: This is still window.

Comment: It depend what is your context when bind occurs. Check `console.log(this)` before bind

Comment: In the users code, this is window at that moment. I dont need to check. I know

Comment: So your solution to use `bind(Img)` to get Img as your bound context for IIFE

Comment: Now ypur code is acceptable. Still doesnt answer the question, but i remobe the downvote

Comment: If I understand correct - you need right `this` and right `counter` inside your IIFE? If yes - check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var Img = new Image();
    Img.onload = (function(index) {
        return function() {
            console.log(index)
            console.log(this.tagName)
        }
    })(i).bind(Img);
    Img.src = "img.png";
}
```